# Delphi IDE disable Sync Edit Mode

Tags: delphi, ide

Delphi IDE has a Sync Edit button that shows when you select multiple lines of text
Is there any way to disable this?

[image: Sync Edit]

we suspect that its making mouse scrolling while text is selected painfully slow on some machines

[Scrolling video example of why we think its the sync edit that's slowing down scrolling](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByFOyj5aq4RNX0djcG1sRjZrLVU/view)

Steps to reproduce 
1) Create a Unit in Delphi
2) add about 100 lines with random text
3) Have no lines selected/Highlited - Use the Mouse wheel to scroll (Should be no lag)
3) make only one line selected/Highlited - Use the Mouse wheel to scroll (Should be no lag)
4) make multiple lines selected/Highlited - Use the Mouse wheel to scroll (you will notice a lag in the scrolling - if you look close you notice that the sync edit appears to have reprinted making a different color where it has attempted to do this 15 secs into the video)

[image: Scroll lag]

This is the reason why i suspect the Sync edit button

Comment: There's no way (at least in any of the Tools->Options entries) to disable it. However, I've never had an issue with SyncEdit impacting scrolling, and I deal with some very large projects every day. It doesn't do anything unless you click it to actually do the editing, and its being shown in the gutter doesn't impact scrolling any more than anything else (including a similar button displayed in the gutter by CNWizards).

Comment: we don't know if its the sync edit that's making it slow, but you can see the redraw actually happen on the side. was wondering if we could disable it as we never use it anyway

Comment: So something is making the scrolling slow, and you've jumped to the conclusion that it's SyncEdit. As I said, I work in very large projects every day (one of which is more than a million lines of code, not including some third-party stuff), and never had an issue with SyncEdit. Can you reproduce the problem in another project by repeating the same actions? How much code (in lines) is in the unit where you're having the issue? What third-party addins (editors and wizards) do you have installed?

Comment: on my computer i don't really notice it - i can see that its slightly slower. on another computer in the office it makes using the mouse scroll while text is selected take a few seconds before the scroll finishes and you can use the IDE again - no other plugins installed e.g. cnpack

Comment: Then suspect an issue with that other computer (memory, a hard disk issue, even a buggy video driver). If it was an issue with Delphi, it would probably have an entry in Jira at EMBT (SyncEdit has been around since at least Delphi 2007), and I don't find one there or via a web search.

Comment: its like a dripping tap, once you notice it you cant un notice it. thought it could be like turning off live bindings in the IDE speeds things up a lot.

Comment: Except you're on a wild goose chase, trying to track down a way to hide a symptom instead of actually curing the disease. If you're going to insist on having it your way and ignore suggestions on how to find the real problem, suit yourself. When you've finished wasting your time, come back and read through these comments again and start looking for the actual problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154395/discussion-between-dangas56-and-ken-white).

Comment: CnWizards can slow down text scrolling considerably if it is selected. If you have CnWizards installed, disable it and check again.

Comment: @Alexandre: The [poster already said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208648/delphi-ide-disable-sync-edit-mode#comment79381281_46208648) that there are  no plugins like CNPack installed.